# how to create multiple js files from index.html using grunt usemin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grunt-usemin

My index.html has split js files as follows:

```
<head>
  ....
  <!-- build:js js/app1.min.js -->
  <!-- js from lib -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <!-- js of this app -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  <!-- external js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
  ....
</head>

.....
<body>
...
  <!-- build:js js/app2.min.js -->

  <!-- js from lib -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- angular-animate provides search functionality -->

  <!-- js of this app -->      
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

  <!-- endbuild -->
  ....
</body>
```

As you can see, I tried to use two sets of js files. The reason to split is performance. How to use usemin in this case. I tried with following:

```
'useminPrepare': {
  'html': 'app/index.html'
},

'usemin': {
  'html': ['dist/index.html']
},
```

However, there is no folder/file created. But in index.html, those two sections are replaced appropriately by app1.min.js and app2.min.js

Moreover, I do not understand one thing that all examples are using concat and uglify in combination of usemin. The files in index.html which are already *.min.js eg. files included in bower_components folder, what happens to them?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're heavily invested in `grunt` already, give `gulp` a look.

Below is a snippet from `gulpfile.js`.  The `gulp.src()` functions take a list of files, then pipe them through transformations, ending with a list of files, which get's written to disk with `gulp.dest()`.

This let's the first two blocks of code src, transform (minify,concat,etc), and write the js and css.

The last block of code src()'s the index.html, injects the filenames from the first two blocks, and writes the index.html to a build folder.  I do consulting on gulp builds.

Here's how you'd do it in gulp:

```
  // Vendor files are pre-minified.  Get right versions.
  // JS.  Concat, and add revision if necessary
  var srcJs = config.minify ? config.dashboard.vendorJsMin : config.dashboard.vendorJs;
  var destJs = 'vendor' + (config.minify?'.min':'') + '.js';
  var vendorJs = gulp.src(srcJs)
  .pipe(plugins.if(config.concat, plugins.concat(destJs)))
  .pipe(plugins.if(config.hash, plugins.hash()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dashboard.dest + '/js'))

  // Vendor files are pre-minified.  Get right versions.
  // CSS.  Concat, and add revision if necessary
  var srcCss = config.minify ? config.dashboard.vendorCssMin : config.dashboard.vendorCss;
  var destCss = 'vendor' + (config.minify?'.min':'') + '.css';
  var vendorCss = gulp.src(srcCss)
  .pipe(plugins.if(config.concat, plugins.concat(destCss)))
  .pipe(plugins.if(config.hash, plugins.hash()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dashboard.dest + '/css'))

  // Inject all these files into index.html
  return gulp.src(config.dashboard.index)
  .pipe(plugins.plumber())
  .pipe(plugins.inject(vendorJs, _.merge({name: 'vendor'}, config.dashboard.injectOptions)))
  .pipe(plugins.inject(vendorCss, _.merge({name: 'vendor'}, config.dashboard.injectOptions)))
  .pipe(plugins.inject(appJs, _.merge({name: 'app'}, config.dashboard.injectOptions)))
  .pipe(plugins.inject(appCss, _.merge({name: 'app'}, config.dashboard.injectOptions)))
  .pipe(plugins.inject(templates, _.merge({name: 'templates'}, config.dashboard.injectOptions)))
  .pipe(plugins.replace('REPLACE_NODE_ENV', config.NODE_ENV))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dashboard.dest))
```

This is a much more 'dev' like build system than grunt.  Grunt is much more 'ops' like.  Whatever works best is the one to use!